# Must one say a blessing before writing Torah thoughts?

Tags: halacha, blessing, torah-study, birchos-hatorah, chiddush

Suppose one wakes up in the morning, and comes up with a [chiddush](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chidush) in some subject of Torah. Must he say the [blessing for studying Torah](http://www.beingjewish.com/torahblessings.html) before writing it down?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Shulhan Arukh (OH 47:3) writes that one must make the blessing even upon writing. He does not specify that this be the writing of new ideas. In the Beit Yosef (3) to the Tur there, he quotes this from Abudirham.

This is also the implication of the Pri Megadim (MZ 2) and the conclusion of the Arokh HaShulhan (47:10).

However, the Mishna Berura there (4) states that one should be stringent and not recite the blessing on mere writing, but only on speech. Accordingly one should say some of the words he is writing, or other words of Torah after the blessing.

Regarding the question of whether typing is considered writing, see [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/14157/8775).

Comment: What about electric typing? In the OPs case he could maybe type it into his phone and avoid the bracha

Comment: @DoubleAA sounds great, for Shabbos purposes, it isn't considered writing.(except the electric part which falls under a different question)

Comment: @doub it is an interesting avenue to pursue. While difficult to prove anything about this  conclusively, my inclination is that the idea in rishonim, that aharonim apply here, that blessing are generally instituted on actions not thoughts (perhaps because the former are more quantifiable) would allow for typing just as they explain it applies to writing.